# How to convert ETH (Ethereum) to XRP (Ripple)

Tags: ether

I have some ETH (Ethereum) in a private wallet. How can I buy XRP (Ripple) with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use instant exchanges such as:

- Changelly https://www.changelly.com
- Shapeshift https://shapeshift.io/

Changelly has better max volume per operation and I recommend it.

Or you can exchange on any major cryptoexchange.

Comment: There is another method I found: Open an XRP wallet in gatehub.net, and gatehub fifth let's you exchange ETH for XRP.